# RTK query Error encountered handling the endpoint

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm using next.js with RTK query. I created api, configured endpoints with `queryFn` instead of `query` and got an error:

Error

How I can fix this error?

ContentStore.ts

```
export const contentApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api/content',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: ''
    }),
    endpoints: (build) => ({
        getNewMovies: build.query<any, ContentApi.GetNewMoviesRequestParams>({
            queryFn: (params: ContentApi.GetNewMoviesRequestParams) => ContentApiClient.getNewMovies(params),
        })
    })
})
```

ContentApiClient.ts

```
class ContentApiClientClass extends ApiClientClass {
    baseUrl = ContentApiClientConstants.baseUrl

    async getNewMovies(params?: ContentApi.GetNewMoviesRequestParams) {
        return await this.getRequest({
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
            params
        })
    }
}

export const ContentApiClient = new ContentApiClientClass()
```

ApiClient.class.ts

```
class ApiClientClass {
    axiosInstance: AxiosInstance

    constructor(config?: AxiosRequestConfig) {
        this.axiosInstance = this.createInstance(config)
    }

    private createInstance(config?: AxiosRequestConfig) {
        return axios.create({
            ...config,
            timeout: 60000,
            headers: {
                'Cache-control': 'no-cache',
                ...(config?.headers || {})
            }
        })
    }

    private async axiosRequest<R>(context: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosResponse<R>> {
        try {
            return await this.axiosInstance(context)
        } catch (error) {
            if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
                throw new Error(`Request has aborted. Url: ${context.url}`)
            }

            throw error
        }
    }

    async getRequest<R>(context: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosResponse<R>> {
        return await this.axiosRequest({
            ...context,
            method: 'get'
        })
    }
}

export default ApiClientClass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `queryFn` has to return an object in either the shape `{ data: something }` or `{ error: something }`. It should not `throw` anything.

That said, you are doing a *lot* of stuff here just to do an api request. While it is certainly possible to go to that length, I'd really recommend you to just use `baseQuery` with the `query` function. `baseFetchQuery` should do everything you need, but if you're hell-bent on adding another 6kb of bundle size for axios, the documentation also has examples on how to write an axios baseQuery.